# Projection On Parallelogram

Tags: geometry, reference-request, coordinate-systems, projective-geometry, computational-geometry

In my research, I encountered the problem of finding the projection of any point on given parallelogram with the following properties :

[image]

1. If the point is in region 1, the projection should be vertex A.
2. If the point is in region 2, the projection should be on segment AB parallel to Y-axis.
3. If the point is in region 3, the projection should be vertex B.

And so on.

The equations of parallelogram sides are also given in the figure.

I am trying to find out a computational way to figure out this projection.

I tried to set up the problem as a minimum L1 distance to parallelogram from the given point. But, I realized that this is not the correct projection.

Can some one provide help on what would be the efficient computational way to figure out this kind of projection? I am totally new to this field - Any references are highly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There are some conditions to make clear: a) you said that AB is parallel to y axis, but then what are the dotted lines out of B indicating ? b) the arrow indicating the projection, is it normal to the edge ?, parallel to the axes ? ...  c) the drawing is so distorted that looks to be in 3D, but equations are in 2d (?) You should provide a much cleaner scheme , before thinking to equations

Comment: @GCab: a) AB is not parallel to y-axis. I meant the projection is parallel to y-axis. For example, let X be the given point in region 2 then Y is projection of X such that XY is parallel to Y-axis. b) Parallel to axes. c) The diagram is 2D and the shape is parallelogram and the describing equations are also in the diagram. Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 3):

[image: Parallog_Proj_1]

So, each couple of lines given by 
$$
b_{\,1,\,1} x + b_{\,1,\,2} y =  \pm 1
$$
and
$$
b_{\,2,\,1} x + b_{\,2,\,2} y =  \pm 1
$$
denotes a couple of lines symmetrical wrt the origin.

The four lines defines a parallelogram centered at the origin.

The four vertices are given by
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   {A_{\,p,\,p} } & {A_{\,p,\,m} } & {A_{\,m,\,p} } & {A_{\,m,\,m} }  \cr  } } \right)
\; : \; \left( {\matrix{
   {b_{\,1,\,1} } & {b_{\,1,\,2} }  \cr 
   {b_{\,2,\,1} } & {b_{\,2,\,2} }  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{   x  \cr    y  \cr  } } \right)
 = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 1 & { - 1} & { - 1}  \cr 
   1 & { - 1} & 1 & { - 1}  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
i.e.:
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   {A_{\,p,\,p} } & {A_{\,p,\,m} } & {A_{\,m,\,p} } & {A_{\,m,\,m} }  \cr  } } \right)
 = \left( {\matrix{ {b_{\,1,\,1} } & {b_{\,1,\,2} }  \cr    {b_{\,2,\,1} } & {b_{\,2,\,2} }  \cr  } } \right)^{\, - \,1}
 \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1 & { - 1} & { - 1}  \cr    1 & { - 1} & 1 & { - 1}  \cr  } } \right)
$$

If some of the $b$ values are negative the denomination of the A points will change
with respect to that shown in the figure: it is better to rearrange the denominations as to match
with that shown, i.e. lower, higher $x$, lower,higher $y$ coordinates.

Now, at each vertex attach three unitary vectors as shown.

Compute the projection of the vector $A_{p,m}P$ onto the unitary vectors $\bf x_{pm}$ and $\bf y_{pm}$ stemming from $A_{p,m}$.
If both projections are positive, then the point P lies in the $90^\circ$ sector encompassed by those vectors
 and $P$ projects onto the vertex itself.
Repeat for the other vertices and check if both projections are positive.

If P is not in any of the sector above, then express the vector $A_{p,m}P$ in the reference system given by $\bf x_{pm}, \, \bf v_{pm}$.
If the coordinates in that system are both positive, then $P$ projects on the edge $A_{pm}A_{pp}$, and its
coordinate wrt  $\bf v_{pm}$ gives the distance from the vertex  $A_{pm}.

You can see that the reference system $\bf y_{pp}, \, \bf v_{pp}$ in $A_{pp}$ will cover the edge $A_{pp}A_{mp}$, and so on.
You can also see that $P$, if external to the parallelogram, can have both coordinates positive only in one of the four systems.

To translate the above into a *computational algorithm* we can proceed along the following lines.

[image: Parallog_Proj_2]

a) Construct the matrix 
$$
{\bf B} = \left( {\matrix{
   {b_{\,1,\,1} } & {b_{\,1,\,2} }  \cr 
   {b_{\,2,\,1} } & {b_{\,2,\,2} }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
ensure that its determinant is non null and compute $\bf B^{-1}$.

b) Compute the four points A
$$
\left( {\matrix{   {A_{\,p,\,p} } & {A_{\,p,\,m} } & {A_{\,m,\,p} } & {A_{\,m,\,m} }  \cr  } } \right)
 = {\bf B}^{\, - \,1} \left( {\matrix{   1 & 1 & { - 1} & { - 1}  \cr    1 & { - 1} & 1 & { - 1}  \cr  } } \right)
$$

c) Rearrange points A
for instance by taking as pivot the point with minimal abscissa ($A_0$ in the sketch) and arranging the others 
according to the tangent of the angle that they form with the pivot (if $\Delta x = 0 \; \to \; \Delta x = \epsilon $);
re-name the suffixes to $(0,1,2,3)$ so that they increase along the perimeter (e.g. ACW).

d) Construct unit vectors $\bf u_n, \; v_n$
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf v}_{\,n}  = \overrightarrow {A_{\,n} A_{\,\left( {n + 1} \right)} } \mathop {\;/}\limits_{} \;\left| {\overrightarrow {A_{\,n} A_{\,\left( {n + 1} \right)} } } \right|\quad \left( {n\bmod 4} \right)  \cr 
  & {\bf u}_{\,n}  = \left( {\matrix{
   {\cos \left( {\left( {n - 2} \right)\pi /2} \right)}  \cr 
   {\sin \left( {\left( {n - 2} \right)\pi /2} \right)}  \cr 
 } } \right) \cr} 
$$

e) Allocate the point P in the corresponding sector
construct the two lists
$$
L_{\,x}  = \left[ {A_{\,n,\,x} ,P_{\,x} } \right]\quad L_{\,y}  = \left[ {A_{\,n,\,y} ,P_{\,y} } \right]
$$
and sort them in increasing order;

f) use the rank indices of P in the ordered lists to determine its position and projection
  if (corner sector in $A_0$)
    $P_{\,x}  < A_{\,0,\,x} \; \wedge \;A_{\,0,\,y}  < P_{\,y} $ then $P \to A_{\,0} $ exit;
  elif  (lateral sector below $A_0$)
    $P_{\,x}  < A_{\,1,\,x} \; \wedge \;A_{\,1,\,y}  < P_{\,y}  < A_{\,0,\,y} $ then
 - take the matrix ${\bf V}_{\,0}  = \left( {\matrix{   {{\bf u}_{\,0} } & {{\bf v}_{\,0} }  \cr  } } \right)$
 - determine the coordinates of $P$ in that system
$$
\left( {\matrix{   {P'_x }  \cr    {P'_y }  \cr  } } \right)
 = {\bf V}_{\,0} ^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} \;\left( {\matrix{   {P_x }  \cr    {P_y }  \cr  } } \right)
$$
 - if $P'_y<0 \; \to$ error;
 - elif $P'_x<0 \; \to$ the point is internal to the p., $\to$ ?
 - else  $P\; \to \;A_{\,0}  + P'_y {\bf v}_{\,0} $
  elif
 ....
(continue with the same path for the other sectors)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sure if I can code this - Do you think it can be expressed in a computational way? For example: We would like to write a function which takes the matrix B and point P (x,y) as inputs and computes (X,Y) as projection? Also, I would like to extend this Algorithm to high dimensions - so checking all the vertices will be susceptible to curse of dimensionality! Please let me know. Thanks Much.

Comment: @chandu1729: well I developed the answer mainly mathematically, but keeping an eye on computability. Mathematically (and computationally) I cannot see a better way. And it can be extended to 3D and higher. I am quite sure it is tranformable in an algorithm.

Comment: @chandu1729: the difficulty, is mainly on rotation /reflection of the points for negative signs on the $b$'s. If the $b$'s are positive it should be quite viable.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking/traversing at each vertex. In n-dimensions there will be 2^n vertices which makes it exponential complexity!

Comment: I would highly appreciate if you can express your answer in an algorithmic way for general n-dimensional matrix B and point P. That will be easier for me to understand as well.

Comment: @chandu1729: that step can be reduced by exploiting the fact that the figure is centered at the origin and we can determine a couple of sides  to which P is nearer. Note that if the projection was orthogonal, the problem would be simpler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85899/discussion-between-chandu1729-and-g-cab).

Comment: @chandu1729: added a sketch for a computing algorithm: hope it fixes the matter.

Comment: Thanks much. How does it scale in high dimensions? Let's say the function has to compute this projection and the inputs are  n-dimensional Matrix B and point P in n-dimensions.  If we start to compute vertices and traverse the way you suggested, it would become exponential complexity essentially unusable in high-dimensions.

Comment: @chandu1729: if the projection was taken parallel to the sides, then it would be much simpler: we could transform the parallelogram into a square and work in that reference system. Not being so, if we use that reference then the projection becomes obliquous and also the corners: no much gain. Apart from that I do not know how to make it simpler, specially in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

In my solution $x_1, x_2$ are replaced by $x,y.$
The solution should be easy to code.

Assume the given straight lines are not horizontal neither vertical. In this case are all coefficients $b_{ij}\neq 0.$
From the coefficients $\pm 1$ in the equations follows that the parallelogram is centered in $O.$
Thus if $A(x_A,y_A), B(x_B,y_B),$ then necessarily $C(-x_A,-y_A), D(-x_B,-y_B).$

In the enclosed figure are the equations of the straight lines $\color{blue}{blue},$ and located across the corresponding line.

[image]

Each region is determined by a system of inequations written in *black*.

The input point $P(x,y)$ has to be transformed to an output $P'(X,Y).$ These new coordinates $X,Y$ are written in the corresponding region in $\color{red}{red}.$

**Remark**
If a pair of lines is horizontal or vertical (the product $\prod_{i,j=1,2} b_{ij}=0$ ), the above solution has to be modified, but is easier.